# Rspec with Capybara have_css matcher is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

In Cucumber, with Rspec and Capybara I have a test to check that a button has a class. Here it is

```
expect(@some_button).to have_css(".in-cart")
```

it fails, but

```
@some_button['class']
```

returns

```
'btn product in-cart'
```

so the button definitely has the 'in-cart' class.

As a temporary measure I've changed my test to be;-

```
expect(@some_button['class']).to match /in-cart/
```

Which is obviously insane. But why should 'have_css', or 'has_css?' return false for a DOM element that clearly has the expected class?

Also page.all('.in-cart') includes the button, so Capybara can definitely find it.

Incidentally I also tried 'button.in-cart', 'in-cart',expect (etc).to have_selector, expect(etc.has_selector?('.in-cart')).to be_truthy and all combinations.

Comment: what happens when you try `expect(@some_button).to have_css("btn.product.in-cart")`

Answer (score 10):

`have_css` matcher is expected to be applied to the parent container instead of the actual element

```
# your view
<div id="container">
  <div class="in_cart product"></div>
</div>

# your step definition
parent = page.find('div#container')
expect(parent).to have_css(".in-cart")
# => returns true, as there is nested div.in_cart
expect('div#container div').to have_css(".in-cart")
# => returns false, as there is no such selector inside of the latter div
```

As of matching attributes of the exact object, you've got to stick with simple quering by key

```
element = page.find('div#container div')
element['class'].should include('in-cart')
expect(element['class']).to match /in-cart/
```

Same logic applies to all of the [RSpecMatchers](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers).

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Capybara/Rspec, by default, `expect(page)` will query the entire page looking for a match; however, sometimes we may not want that and instead will prefer to target a specific class/region of the page. For those cases, narrow down the context of `page` using `within`:

```
within('.container') do
  expect(page).to have_css(".in-cart")
end
```

Assuming, the parent has a class `container` Capybara will only search within this element.

Answer (score -1):

expect(page).to have_css('button.in-cart')

Comment: yes it does -- that would check the page has a button with the class in-cart which is exactly what the author states he wants to do

Comment: This looks like you're searching the whole page for any button with the class `.in-cart`. I thought the question was about checking that a *particular* button had that class?